# Update Table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, socket.io

In server side, I emit last 10 rows of my database in every 3 second;

```
setInterval(function() {
              connection.query("SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY id DESC limit 10", function(err, rows) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {
                  console.log("Last 10 record emitted.");
                //  console.log("rows: " + JSON.stringify(rows, null, 3));
                  io.emit("last_list", rows)
                }
              });
            }, 3000);
```

In client side, I append these rows to table;

```
  socket.on('last_list', function(rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = rows[i];

      $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td><td>' + row.fabrika + '</td><td>' +
      row.kumes + '</td><td>' + row.makina + '</td><td>' + row.kat + '</td><td>' +
      row.sol_sag + '</td><td style="color: rgba(25, 44, 44, 1); font-weight: bolder;">' +
      row.adet + '</td></tr>');

    }
  });
```

My question is, how can I update table instead of add new rows every 3 seconds?

Comment: What's the difference between adding new rows and updating table ?

Comment: Does that mean you want to clear the table and re-load the whole data?

Comment: @user1041953 This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @erayaras but your current approach is much better than clearing the table every time. It may get the browser stuck in devices with low-CPU power.

Comment: Anyway, it's better to use a template-engine like [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) in order to get rid of inline-HTML in the JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the table body every time before append. You can either give your tbody an ID and clear it like  $("#tbody").html("")  or you can use the following way.

```
socket.on('last_list', function(rows) {
$('#myTable tbody').html("");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var row = rows[i];



  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td><td>' + row.fabrika + '</td><td>' +
  row.kumes + '</td><td>' + row.makina + '</td><td>' + row.kat + '</td><td>' +
  row.sol_sag + '</td><td style="color: rgba(25, 44, 44, 1); font-weight: bolder;">' +
  row.adet + '</td></tr>');

}
```

});

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myTable').empty();
```

Just add above list as the first line of your callback function i.e.:

```
socket.on('last_list', function(rows) {
  $('#myTable').empty();
  //REST OF YOUR CODE AS IS HERE...
});
```

*FYI: Just for better performance, don't change the DOM with every loop. Instead keep adding rows to a variable and than assign that to your table after the loop. DOM operations are expensive than variables.*

Answer (score 1):

Keep your data in the array. Every time new data comes append it to the array and re-render your array with updated dataset. Like this:

```
var data = []
var tableContainer = $('#myTable')

function renderTable() {
  tableContainer.innerHTML = data.map(function(row) {
    return '<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td><td>' + row.fabrika + '</td><td>' +
      row.kumes + '</td><td>' + row.makina + '</td><td>' + row.kat + '</td><td>' +
      row.sol_sag + '</td><td style="color: rgba(25, 44, 44, 1); font-weight: bolder;">' +
      row.adet + '</td></tr>'
  }).join('')
}

function updateData(newData) {
  newData.forEach(function(item) {
    data.push(item)
  })
}

socket.on('last_list', function(rows) {
  updateData(rows)
  renderTable()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$().empty` to clear the content of `table` and then use `$().append` or `$().html` to put the html content.

Also instead of using string  and concatenating each variable, you can make use of `template string` i.e `backticks` to create mutliline html content more conveniently.

```js
function generateTable(row) {

  return `
      <tr>
        <td>${row.id}</td>
        <td>${row.fabrika}</td>
        <td>${row.kumes}</td>
        <td>${row.makina}</td>
        <td>${row.kat}</td>
        <td>${row.sol_sag}</td>
        <td style="color: rgba(25, 44, 44, 1); font-weight: bolder;">${row.adet}</td>
       </tr>
     `
}

var rows = [{
  id: '1',
  fabrika: '2',
  kumes: '3',
  makina: '4',
  kat: '5',
  sol_sag: '6',
  adet: '7'
}, {
  id: '2',
  fabrika: '3',
  kumes: '4',
  makina: '5',
  kat: '6',
  sol_sag: '7',
  adet: '8'
}]

setTimeout(() => {
  $('table').empty();
  $('table').append(generateTable(rows[0]));
}, 1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  $('table').empty();
  $('table').append(generateTable(rows[1]));
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
</table>
```